# How to change target url based on git branche?

Tags: git, teamcity

We are using TeamCity with the Deployer plugin and we need to copy our build into a remote server. The server adress will depend on the git branche.

> For example : branche master as "target url : \server1\dev\" | branche trunk will be in "\server2\dev"

I tried to specify it in the Build Step, with the runner : "SMB Deployer" but can't change between server 1 or 2.

Is there a way to change the server adress based on the git branche ?

Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to make 2 "Build Configuration" and it seems to work.

1 Build Configuration / branch.

Hope it will be helpful for the next. :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the variable containing the build branch: %teamcity.build.branch%

For more details: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Predefined+Build+Parameters#PredefinedBuildParameters-BranchRelatedParameters

Comment: I already searched in this documentation. But I though that with this variable we couldn't specify a condition like "if branch = master then targeturl = server1" thanks for your help